# GNU 'make -j' causes high cpu load and desktop no response

Tags: makefile

I am using kubuntu 10.10 with a 4 cores cpu. When I use 'make -j2' to build a cpp project, 2 core's cup usage become 100%, desktop environment become no response, and build procedure make no progress.

Version info:

```
The GNU make's version is 3.81 
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

How to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is it 2 cores with hyper threading or 4 physical cores?

Comment: @JesusRamos I believe it is 4 physical cores :)

Comment: Does it only happen on Ubuntu? Since 2 cores are being used your desktop should still be pretty responsive

Comment: @JesusRamos No, it also happen on our new CentOS build machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really enough information here to give you a definitive answer.  First it's not clear if this happens only when you run with -j2.  What if you run without parallelism (no -j)?  When you say "2 core's CPU usage [goes to] 100%", what is happening on those CPUs?  If you run "top" in another terminal and then start your build, what is showing in top?

Alternatively, if you run "make -d -j2" what program(s) is make running right before the CPU goes to 100%?

The fact that the desktop is unresponsive as well hints at some other problem, rather than CPU usage, since you have 4 cores and only 2 are busy.  Maybe something is chewing up all your RAM?  Does the system come back after a while (indicating that the OOM killer got involved and stomped something)?

If none of that helps, you can run make under strace, something like "strace -f make -j2" and see if you can figure out what is going on.  This will generate a metric ton or two of output but if, when the CPU is pegged, you see something running over and over and over you might get a hint.

Basically I can see these possibilities:

1. It's not make at all, but rather whatever command make is running that's just bringing your system down.  You imply it's just compiling C++ code so that seems unlikely unless there's a bug somewhere.
2. Make is recursing infinitely.  Make will rebuild its own makefile, plus any included makefile, then re-exec itself.  If you are not a bit careful defining rules for rebuilding included makefiles make can decide they're always out of date and rebuild/rexec forever.
3. Something else

Hopefully the above hints will set you on a path to discovering what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the project is prepared for parallel compilation? Maybe the prerequisites aren't correctly ordered.

If you build the project with just "make" the compilation finish? If it gets to the end is a target dependency problem.